# Batch - Act upon files that are ONLY in folders with specific name

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, 7zip

I have the following FOR statement:

```
 FOR /R %%i IN ("*.wmv") DO "7za.exe" -sdel a -mx0 -tzip -pPASSWORDHERE -mem=AES256 -y "%%~dpni.zip" "%%i"
```

that when ran at the root folder of any given directory, it will zip all files matching the defined wildcard (wmv files, in this case), producing an encrypted ZIP file, keeping the original name.

What I need to do is to tell this script to act ONLY on folders that have a specific name. Here's an example:

I have a directory structure that resembles this (and will contain wmv files in subdirectories within them):

```
root
 |-20120211
   |-20
   |-21
 |-20130425
   |-34
   |-21
 |-20140516
   |-10
   |-22
 |-20150728
   |-230
   |-213
 and so on...
```

And what I need to do is, for example, to only zip all the files that are inside of the last folder, which filename starts with 2015*

To accomplish this, I've tried concatenating FOR statements, more specifically, something like:

```
 FOR /D %%P IN (2015*) DO (run my other FOR here)
```

but the only thing it accomplishes is just to verify if a folder's name within that structure matches "2015*", and if it does... well... it just zips everything, all the files in all folders, not just those that start with "2015".

I've searched the web but found no actual example that could help me with this. If you could aid me in achieving this, I'll be beholden to you =)

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: What about not using a `for /R` loop, but: `for /D %%D in ("root\2015*") do for %%F in ("%%~D\*.wmv") do ( ... )`? Or, in case `-20`, `-21`, etc. are folders as well which contain all the `*.wmv` files: `for /D %%D in ("root\2015*") do for /D %%E in ("%%~D\*") do for %%F in ("%%~E\*.wmv") do ( ... )` (using `"%%~F"` in the inner loop body both times)

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /D %%P IN (2015*) DO PUSHD "%%P"&(FOR /R %%i IN ("*.wmv") DO ECHO %%i)&POPD
```

should accomplish the task, given the description.

Filename simply `echo`ed. Remember that the current directory will be the file-to-be-archived's directory at the time the `echo` is executed, so replacing the `echo` with the archive instruction will require the required destination directory be specified

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot work as `for /R` does not accept `for` variables nor delayed expanded variables in the root directory; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40503715) for a work-around...

Comment: @aschipfl : Good spotting again! Always happens when you haven't *actually* tested a suggestion. Revised solution posted...

Comment: Yes, I know, happed to me several times too... Nice work-around! The only thing I don't like that much is the fact that there is a single `pushd` but multiple `popd`-s; what about enclosing the inner `for /R` loop in parentheses, including the `echo` or `7za` but excluding `pushd` and `popd`? this ensures that the code works even if inserted in between another `pushd`/`popd` block? remember that `%%i` expands to full paths anyway due to `for /R`...

Comment: @aschipfl: Yes, done. Second faulty method deleted. I ran the test with multiple target files, but without prior `push` so the stack was immediately exhaused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the items `20`, `21`, etc., are folders as well, which contain all the `*.wmv` files, the following should work:

```
for /D %%D in ("root\2015*") do (
    for /D %%E in ("%%~D\*") do (
        for %%F in ("%%~E\*.wmv") do (
            "7za.exe" -sdel a -mx0 -tzip -pPASSWORDHERE -mem=AES256 -y "%%~dpnF.zip" "%%~F"
        )
    )
)
```

---

In case the `*.wmv` files may also be located in the parent folders like `20150728`, you could nest a `for /R` loop in a `for /D` loop, like this:

```
for /D %%D in ("root\2015*") do (
    call :SUB "%%~D"
)
exit /B

:SUB
for /R "%~1" %%F in ("*.wmv") do (
    "7za.exe" -sdel a -mx0 -tzip -pPASSWORDHERE -mem=AES256 -y "%%~dpnF.zip" "%%~F"
)
exit /B
```

You need a sub-routine here, because `for /R` does not accept other `for` variables to be used as the root after `/R`. This is due to the fact that the root is applied in a very early parsing stage where `for` variables are not yet processed/expanded.